# Same dialog is showing by click on different buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

have a look at the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/aashi/LyrXA/)..there is some prob in jquery as when i click on either button still only 1 popup is shown

*Script*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#btnShowSimple").click(function (e) {
       ShowDialog(false);
       $("#model").reveal();
       e.preventDefault();
   });
   $("#btnShowShare").click(function (e) {
       ShowDialog(false);
       $("#model1").reveal();
       e.preventDefault();
   });
   $("#btnClose").click(function (e) {
       HideDialog();
       e.preventDefault();
   });
   $(document).keyup(function (e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 27) {
           HideDialog();
       }
   });
});

function ShowDialog(modal) {
   $("#overlay").show();
   $("#dialog").fadeIn(300);
   if (modal) {
       $("#overlay").unbind("click");
   } else {
       $("#overlay").click(function (e) {
           HideDialog();
       });
   }
}

function HideDialog() {
   $("#overlay").hide();
   $("#dialog").fadeOut(300);
}
```

Comment: Always include the relevant code and markup __in__ the question, don't just link (not even to a fiddle). Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: What does `.reveal()` do?

Comment: why you are using same id for output,overlay,dialog. id should be unique

Comment: What do you want different dialog to be? In your fiddle code, you have only one dialog, and through your hide/show functions, you are hiding and showing that same dialog. Do you want your dialog to show different text? Like when you click on email, the text should show "Email this article" and when you click on share the text should show "Share this article"? Please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
 {
   $("#btnShowSimple").click(function (e)
    {
     ShowDialog('dialog');
     $("#model").reveal();
     e.preventDefault();
   });
   $("#btnShowShare").click(function (e)
    {
     ShowDialog('dialog1');
     $("#model1").reveal();
     e.preventDefault();
   });
   $("#btnClose").click(function (e)
    {
     HideDialog();
     e.preventDefault();
   });
  $("#btnClose1").click(function (e)
  {
     HideDialog();
     e.preventDefault();
  });
   $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
         HideDialog(); }
  });
 });
  function ShowDialog(modal)
   {
    $("#overlay").show();
    $("#"+modal).fadeIn(300);
    if (modal)
    {
     $("#overlay").unbind("click");
    }
   else
    {
     $("#overlay").click(function (e)
     {
        HideDialog();
     });
  }
 }
function HideDialog()
 {
    $("#overlay").hide();
    $(".web_dialog").fadeOut(300);
 }
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Gu6zU/

You have to use unique id for div.